# Excel VBA code causing crash - Unknown reason

Tags: vba, excel, crash

Could anyone please tell me why the following code would cause an Excel 2010 crash:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As range)
Dim r As range
Dim r1 As range
Dim c As range
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim rows As Long
Dim count As Long
Dim sheet As String
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim range1 As range
Dim range2 As range

If WorksheetFunction.CountA(range("D5:H16")) <= 0 Then
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
End If

Set c = Target

For i = 4 To 8
    For j = 5 To 16
        If Not i = Target.Column Then
            If r Is Nothing Then
                Set r = ActiveSheet.Cells(j, i)
            Else
                Set r = Application.Union(r, ActiveSheet.Cells(j, i))
            End If
        Else
            If r1 Is Nothing Then
                Set r1 = ActiveSheet.Cells(j, i)
            Else
                Set r1 = Application.Union(r1, ActiveSheet.Cells(j, i))
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
rows = Target.row

sheet = CStr(ActiveSheet.Cells(rows, 2).Value)
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheet)
MsgBox (sh.Name)
count = sh.range("J6").End(xlDown).row
MsgBox (count)
Set range1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").range("J6:J" & count)
Set range2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet).range("J6:J" & count)
range1 = range2.Value

If WorksheetFunction.CountA(range("D5:H16")) <= 0 Then
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
Else
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    r1.Cells.Locked = False
    r.Cells.Locked = True
    ActiveSheet.Protect
End If

End Sub
```

What I'm trying to do is to allow a user to select multiple options in a matrix which will then display a list of equipment based on the matrix selection

Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you try to debug your code to find the line where it is crashing? If so, can you point us out to where it is? Thanks

Comment: What is the error message? Where does it crash?

Answer (score 0):

maybe simplifying the code could get you closer to the crashing issue

If I correctly get it, your code could boil down to:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)               
    With Worksheets(CStr(Cells(Target.Row, 2).Value))
        With .Range("J6", .Range("J6").End(xlDown))
            Worksheets("Summary").Range("J6").Resize(.rows.count).Value = .Value
        End With
    End With

    With Range("D5:H16")
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) > 0 Then
            ActiveSheet.Unprotect
            .Locked = True
            Intersect(.Cells, Target.EntireColumn).Locked = False
            ActiveSheet.Protect
        End If
    End With
 End Sub
```

to which I'd add the following issues:

- `Target` size issue

  It seems to me you're assuming that `Target` is always 1 cell `range`, since you're using:

  ```
     Target.Column
     Target.Row
  ```

  which would return the row and column index of a one-cell `range` as well as of the up leftmost cell of a multi cells `range`

  if you actually want to process a 1 cell `range` as `Target` then you must add the following line at the beginning of your sub

  ```
  If Target.count > 1 Then Exit Sub
  ```

  otherwise be informed that your code would virtually *collapse* `Target` to its up leftmost cell

2) `ThisWorkbook` issue

this issue applies if the macro you're starting off from resides in a different workbook than the one the worksheet your're coding `Change` event handler belongs to

let's say:

- your *main* "KickOff" macro resides in some "MyStartingWorkbook" workbook
- when you run it, it'll affect the content of "dataSheet" worksheet of "MyDataWorkbook" workbook
- your `Worksheet_Change()` event handler applies to this latter worksheet (i.e. "dataSheet" worksheet of "MyDataWorkbook" workbook)

then

- at "KickOff" macro starting, `ThisWorkbook` points to "MyStartingWorkbook" workbook
- but as soon as the macro changes the content of "dataSheet" worksheet of "MyDataWorkbook" workbook, the `Worksheet_Change()` event handler of this latter is fired and `ThisWorkbook` switches to "MyDataWorkbook" workbook

  which may not be what you want, if `"Summary"` and `sheet` worksheets are to belong to "MyStartingWorkbook" workbook

Comment: @ZackJoubert , did you get through it?